# Is it possible to keep track of the Revit ribbon buttons which were clicked on?

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I've been trying to figure out a way to record user interface actions to retrieve information about which ribbon buttons were clicked, but I've been unsuccessful so far.

I've spend a lot of time finding the related events in the API, but apparently there are none.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to record user events in Revit. One of the simplest ways is to look at the [journal file](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/journal). It is always generated and stored automatically by Revit, so you don't have to do anything at all to obtain it. Look at its contents; all relevant user interactions are recorded there.

As said, there are other ways as well.

Afaik, recording which buttons are clicked is not officially supported and may be a bit tricky, cf. the Revit API discussion forum thread on [obtaining button name using events for plugins working inside of another plugin](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/obtaining-button-name-using-events-for-plugins-working-inside-of/td-p/11684095).